# Como convertir mi json en una clase

Tags: c#, json

Tengo un problema no se como convertir este json en una clase de c# para despues enviarla por medio de post. eh buscado hasta paginas para convertir un json a clase pero no funciona.

```
{
    findCatalogDataByDefinition(systemCode:"CICAC",countryCode:"CRI",catalogDefCode:"CTG_DISTRITO_AS400",dataCatalog:"",page:0,size:6000){
        content{
            catalogCode
            catalogName
        }
        total
    }
}
```

Yo envio la clase por medio de este codigo

```
_Httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync<string>(_options.Host[0] + _options.Uri[1], ClaseCreada );
```

Comment: Enviar una solicitud HTTP con una clase dentro? No quieres decir enviar un objeto json por Post? Digo, el post ya de por si aguanta enviar parametros por medio de su body y justamente los puedes enviar en formato JSON al backend

Comment: @AlfaRojo Envio la clase por medio de PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: A ver si entiendo... el primer código que pusiste supuestamente es el JSON???

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
public class RootObject {
    public FindCatalogDataByDefinition findCatalogDataByDefinition { get; set; } }

public class FindCatalogDataByDefinition {
    public List<Content> content { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; } }
 

    public class Content
    {
        public string catalogCode { get; set; }
        public string catalogName { get; set; }
    }
```